# Use TouchID as mouse - Any way to get serial output from the chip?

Tags: hardware, mouse, touch-id, authentication

I am investigating the opportunities to use the TouchID as a mouse pointer. Is there any way to read any data except authentication-status from the TouchID chip?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way of doing that. You cannot get raw readings from the sensor (unless you're tearing the device apart and interfacing directly).

Comment: …and even if you could, it's not going to be outputting positional data. It's a one-trick pony & being a trackpad is not that trick;)